# HiveQL: how to find the duplicate elements in a column of array<string>

Tags: arrays, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am creating a table in HiveQL and one column `duplicate_set` should be array containing the set of duplicated elements in a list from another column `list`. For example given a table

```
+-----------+-------------------------+----------------------+
|     id    |              list       |     duplicate_set    |
+-----------+-------------------------+----------------------+
|      1    | ["1","2","2","3","3"]   | ["2","3"]            |
+-----------+-------------------------+----------------------+
|      2    | ["2","2","5","6"]       | ["2"]                |
+-----------+-------------------------+----------------------+
|      3    | ["2","4","5","6"]       | []                   |
...
```

what could be the best way to extract the duplicated elements and put them in a set? Any existing UDF for it? Thanks.

Comment: do you have an `array` column in the original table?

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala, not sure if I understand correctly, the list column is the array<string> column.

Comment: you want an empty list also if element is not duplicated? correct

Answer (score 2):

You can explode array, calculate `row_number`, then aggregate duplicated elements (with row_number>1) into set:

```
with initial_data as (
select 1 id   ,array("1","2","2","3","3") list union all
select 2   ,array("2","2","5","6") list union all    
select 3   ,array("2","4","5","6")  
)    

select s.id, s.list, collect_set(case when s.rn>1 then x end) duplicate_set 
from(
select s.id, s.list, l.x, row_number() over(partition by id, l.x) as rn
  from initial_data s
       lateral view explode(list) l as x --array element x
) s
group by s.id, s.list;
```

Result:

```
id      list                    duplicate_set
1       ["1","2","2","3","3"]   ["2","3"]
2       ["2","2","5","6"]       ["2"]
3       ["2","4","5","6"]       []
```

Comment: It's an elegant solution. +1.

Comment: this is really great! Thanks @leftjoin